# Finding smallest value for parameterised answer that satisfies condition

Tags: matlab

I want to find the smallest integer `l` that satisfies `l^2 >= x`, and `mod(l,2)=0`.

*In the following example `x=75`, and hence `l=10`, since the previous even number doesn't fulfil the inequation: `8^2 <= 75 <= 10^2`*

I have tried this (ignoring the even-number requirement, which I can't to work):

```
syms l integer
eqn1 = l^2 >= 75;
% eqn2 = mod(l,2) == 0;
[sol_l, param, cond] = solve(eqn1, l, 'ReturnConditions', true);
```

But this does not give me anything helpful directly:

```
sol_l =
k
param =
k
cond =
(75^(1/2) <= k | k <= -75^(1/2)) & in(k, 'integer')
```

I would like to evaluate the conditions on the parameter and find the smallest value that satisfies the conditions.

Also, I would like to enforce the `mod(l,2)=0` condition somehow, but I don't seem to get that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `solve` for this task is like using a cannon to kill a mosquito. Actually, the answer of [Lidia Parrilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8493723/lidia-parrilla) is good and fast, although it can be simplified as follows:

```
l = ceil(sqrt(x));

if (mod(x,2) ~= 0)
    l = l + 1;
end

% if x = 75, then l = 10
```

But I would like to point out something that no one else noticed. The condition provided by the `solve` function for `l^2 >= 75` is:

```
75^(1/2) <= k | k <= -75^(1/2)
```

and it's absolutely correct. Since `l` is being raised to the power of 2, and since a negative number raised to the power of 2 produces a positive number, the equation will always have two distinct solutions: a negative one and a positive one.

For `x = 75`, the solutions will be `l = 10` and `l = -10`. So, if you want to find the smallest number (and a negative number is always smaller than a positive one), the right solution will be:

```
l = ceil(sqrt(x));

if (mod(x,2) ~= 0)
    l = l + 1;
end

l = l * -1;
```

If you want to return both solutions, the result will be:

```
l_pos = ceil(sqrt(x));

if (mod(x,2) ~= 0)
    l_pos = l_pos + 1;
end

l_neg = l_pos * -1;

l = [l_neg l_pos];
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest solution without employing the inequality and `solve` function would be to find the exact solution to your equation `l^2 >= x`, and then finding the next even integer. The code would look like this:

```
x = 75;

y = ceil(sqrt(x)); %Ceil finds the next bigger integer

if(~mod(y,2))   %If it's even, we got the solution
    sol = y;
else            %If not, get the next integer
    sol = y+1;
end
```

The previous code gives the correct solution to the provided example (x = 75; sol = 10)